# Как сделать переключение между окнами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать переключение/переходы между окнами? И еще один момент. Окна открываются со свойствами `position:absolute;top и left` - как это собственно и определено в стиле. А как сделать так, чтобы окна позиционировались под своими ссылками/идентификаторами, т.е. каждое окно выводилось чуть ниже своей ссылки? Благодарю за помощь!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var window = $('.window');
  var close = $('.close');
  $('.tab').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.show();
    window.show();
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').hide();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.hide();
    window.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-selected {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab">1</div>
<div id="2" class="tab">2</div>
<div id="3" class="tab">3</div>
<div id="4" class="tab">4</div>

<div class="window">
  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
  <div class="prev">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос 1. *Как можно сделать переключение/переходы между окнами?*
>   Вопрос 2. *Как сделать так, чтобы окна позиционировались под своими ссылками/идентификаторами, т.е. каждое окно выводилось чуть ниже своей ссылки?*

```
$('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
    var obj = ($(this).hasClass("next")) ? $(this).closest(".window").find(".content:visible + .content") : $(this).closest(".window").find(".content:visible").prev(".content");
    var obj_id =  (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content': '4-content');
    var id = obj_id.split("-")[0];
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + obj_id).show();
    $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
    $("#" + id).addClass("tab-selected");
    $(this).closest(".window").css("top", $("#" + id).offset().top + $("#" + id).height());
});
```

`$(this).closest(".window")` можно заменить на `window`, ввиду того, что `window` у Вас уже объявлено в начале кода.

Чтобы при открытии(при нажатии на блок `.tab`) окно отображалось под активным блоком `tab`, добавьте в конец обработчика `$('.tab').bind('click', function()` строку:

```
window.css("top", $(this).offset().top + $(this).height());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var window = $('.window');
  var close = $('.close');
  $('.tab').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.show();
    window.show();
    window.css("top", $(this).offset().top + $(this).height());
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').hide();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.hide();
    window.hide();
  });

  $('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
    var obj = ($(this).hasClass("next")) ? window.find(".content:visible + .content") : window.find(".content:visible").prev(".content");
    var obj_id = (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content' : '4-content');
    var id = obj_id.split("-")[0];
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + obj_id).show();
    $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
    $("#" + id).addClass("tab-selected");
    window.css("top", $("#" + id).offset().top + $("#" + id).height());
  });

});
```

```css
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-selected {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab">1</div>
<div id="2" class="tab">2</div>
<div id="3" class="tab">3</div>
<div id="4" class="tab">4</div>

<div class="window">
  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
  <div class="prev">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Дополнительно:

> [Начиная с jQuery 3.0, `.bind ()` устарел. Он был заменен методом `.on ()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
>   [для привязки обработчиков событий к документу с jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

---

**UPD:** если блоков больше 4, то ищем `id` последнего блока:

```
var obj_id = (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content' : window.find(".content").last().attr("id"));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var overlay = $('.overlay');
  var window = $('.window');
  var close = $('.close');
  $('.tab').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.show();
    window.show();
    window.css("top", $(this).offset().top + $(this).height());
  });
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').hide();
    $('.tab').removeClass('tab-selected');
    overlay.hide();
    window.hide();
  });

  $('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
    var obj = ($(this).hasClass("next")) ? window.find(".content:visible + .content") : window.find(".content:visible").prev(".content");
    var obj_id = (obj.length > 0) ? obj.attr("id") : (($(this).hasClass("next")) ? '1-content' : window.find(".content").last().attr("id"));
    var id = obj_id.split("-")[0];
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#" + obj_id).show();
    $(".tab").removeClass("tab-selected");
    $("#" + id).addClass("tab-selected");
    window.css("top", $("#" + id).offset().top + $("#" + id).height());
  });

});
```

```css
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-selected {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.window {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab">1</div>
<div id="2" class="tab">2</div>
<div id="3" class="tab">3</div>
<div id="4" class="tab">4</div>
<div id="5" class="tab">5</div>
<div id="6" class="tab">6</div>
<div id="7" class="tab">7</div>

<div class="window">
  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
  <div id="5-content" class="content">Текст 5</div>
  <div id="6-content" class="content">Текст 6</div>
  <div id="7-content" class="content">Текст 7</div>
  <div class="prev">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: @LADYX просто заметите `4-content` в 3-й строке кода на `id` последнего `tab` из Вашего набора. Например, если у Вас последний `tab` имеет `id='10-content'`, то в 3-й строчке решения замените `4-content` на `10-content`

Comment: по привязке - можно, но об этом не было сказано в вопросе, поэтому этого нет в ответе. Пожалуйста, в следующий раз, обязательно указывайте подобные моменты,обновим ответ ближе вечеру (по мск)

Comment: @LADYX поторопились

Comment: @LADYX к сожалению вчера не было времени, обновили ответ

Comment: @LADYX если я пишу, что дам ответ, значит обязательно напишу, не всегда получается по времени. пожалуйста)

Comment: @LADYX не должен, нужно смотреть Ваш код. пример https://jsfiddle.net/b46Lzo1a/2/

Comment: @LADYX Вы же поменяли классы. следовательно уже не `'1-content'`, а  `pp_1-content` https://jsfiddle.net/as4bhLkj/3/  P.S.: строка `var obj_id = ...`